# Create dataframe from dictionary of dictionaries using only a certain key

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries of dictionaries like this:

```
d = [{'c1': {'ignore1': 'me1', 'use': 'me'},
      'c2': {'ignore2': 5., 'use': 12}},
     {'c1': {'ign': 2, 'use': 'me2', 'foo': 123},
      'c2': {'ignore2': 5., 'use': 14}}
    ]
```

and want to build a dataframe like this:

```
    c1  c2
0   me  12
1  me2  14
```

So I want to use only the key `use` from the nested dictionaries and the keys of the main dictionaries serve as column names.

When I do

```
pd.DataFrame.from_records(d)
```

I receive

```
                                         c1                             c2
0       {u'use': u'me', u'ignore1': u'me1'}  {u'use': 12, u'ignore2': 5.0}
1  {u'ign': 2, u'use': u'me2', u'foo': 123}  {u'use': 14, u'ignore2': 5.0}
```

A possible solution could look like this:

```
df2 = pd.io.json.json_normalize(d).filter(regex='.use$')
df2.columns = df2.columns.str.replace('.use', "")
```

which gives me the desired outcome.

Is there a direct way to filter the desired key e.g. by using the `.from_records` in a different way?

Answer (score 1):

One way is to manipulate your dictionary and apply `pd.DataFrame` on your new dictionary:

```
d = [{'c1': {'ignore1': 'me1', 'use': 'me'},
      'c2': {'ignore2': 5., 'use': 12}},
     {'c1': {'ign': 2, 'use': 'me2', 'foo': 123},
      'c2': {'ignore2': 5., 'use': 14}}]

d2 = [{k: v['use'] for k, v in i.items()} for i in d]

# [{'c1': 'me', 'c2': 12}, {'c1': 'me2', 'c2': 14}]

df = pd.DataFrame(d2)

#     c1  c2
# 0   me  12
# 1  me2  14
```

Comment: Yes, that also works; I should do some timings whether that is faster  for huge dictionaries (which I usually have) than the approach I posted...